# How to disable and enable admin console (admin-listener, port 4848) from the command line

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, asadmin

I would like to control when and where the admin service is accessible

How do I do one of the following (if possible)

1. Enable the admin console only from localhost (I know about disable-secure-admin, but still I don't want anyone to see the console login page when they add 4848 in the end) 
   I will use SSH tunnle to connect
2. Or, be able to use a certificate, so only certified clients will be able to even see the console
3. Or, be able on demand to start / stop the admin service when needed, not opening it to the outside world (e.g. start stop __asadmin virtual server)

Is any of the above possible?

Comment: I know it's on the border of serverfault (although similar questions on command line / server admin were posted here, and kept open), if you think it should move there, please comment, I'll close and copy it there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found it by guess-work

Solution to scenario #1

- Make sure you have SSH tunnel on port 4848 first
- Go to Configuration -> server-config -> Network Config -> Network Listeners -> admin-listener
- Under the **General** tab, in the **Address:** field replace `0.0.0.0` to `127.0.0.1`
- Restart the server

Solution to scenario #3

I didn't find any command line way to enable / disable virtual servers, network listeners or protocols, but editing domain.xml shows that it's all there, just comment out and restart.

Answer (score 3):

1. [Use asadmin to update the The HTTP Network Listener named `admin-listener`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggnfu.html#giwls).
2. [asadmin enable-secure-admin-principal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/enable-secure-admin-principal-1.html)
   "Instructs GlassFish Server, when secure admin is enabled, to accept admin requests from clients identified by the specified SSL certificate".
3. [asadmin enable-secure-admin](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/enable-secure-admin-1.html#scrolltoc) "enables secure admin (if it is not already enabled), optionally changing the alias used for DAS-to-instance admin messages or the alias used for instance-to-DAS admin messages".  Also [a good blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/quinn/entry/securing_adminstration_in_glassfish_server1) on the subject.  *This doesn't turn admin on/off, but enables/disables for remote access to the admin console without the complications of (1)*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Command #3 solved my problem. I guess that Glassfish 3(3.1.2.2 (build 5)) in default does not enable secure-admin, so the console is not available.